# Laravel Solr HTTP error: Neither collection nor core set

Tags: php, laravel, search, solr, solarium

I tried installing and setting up solarium and laravel using the guides in this link https://petericebear.github.io/laravel-php-solarium-integration-20160725/ and I am getting this error

```
Solr HTTP error: Neither collection nor core set. (404)
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\solarium\vendor\solarium\solarium\src\Core\Client\Adapter\AdapterHelper.php(31): Solarium\Core\Client\Endpoint->getBaseUri()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\solarium\vendor\solarium\solarium\src\Core\Client\Adapter\Curl.php(72): Solarium\Core\Client\Adapter\AdapterHelper::buildUri(Object(Solarium\Core\Client\Request), Object(Solarium\Core\Client\Endpoint))
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\solarium\vendor\solarium\solarium\src\Core\Client\Adapter\Curl.php(177): Solarium\Core\Client\Adapter\Curl->createHandle(Object(Solarium\Core\Client\Request), Object(Solarium\Core\Client\Endpoint))
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\solarium\vendor\solarium\solarium\src\Core\Client\Adapter\Curl.php(30): Solarium\Core\Client\Adapter\Curl->getData(Object(Solarium\Core\Client\Request), Object(Solarium\Core\Client\Endpoint)) 
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\solarium\vendor\solarium\solarium\src\Core\Client\Client.php(871): Solarium\Core\Client\Adapter\Curl->execute(Object(Solarium\Core\Client\Request), Object(Solarium\Core\Client\Endpoint))
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\solarium\vendor\solarium\solarium\src\Core\Client\Client.php(840): Solarium\Core\Client\Client->executeRequest(Object(Solar
```

```
return [
'endpoint' => [
    'localhost' => [
        'host' => env('SOLR_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('SOLR_PORT', '8983'),
        'path' => env('SOLR_PATH', '/solr/'),
        'core' => env('SOLR_CORE', 'reports')
    ]
]
];
```

Comment: Did you create any collection or core at solr side?

Comment: Are any of the env-variables set? For example - set to an empty value?

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you are using laravel version 5.* .

In the past, the V1 API endpoint solr was not added automatically, so most users set it as path on the endpoint. This bug was discovered with the addition of V2 API support. In almost every setup, the path has to be set to / instead of /solr with this release!

For the same reason it is a must to explicit configure the core or collection.

So an old setting like

```
'path' => '/solr/xxxx/'
```

has to be changed to something like

```
'path' => '/',
'collection' => 'xxxx'
```

[click here for more information](https://github.com/solariumphp/solarium#pitfall-when-upgrading-from-earlier-versions-to-5x)